# An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. - Asps.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i am having this exception coming everytime i run and try to create the post..

i am having a simple User,Post,Comment,Tag entity. which has relationship association defined by me. when i am checking the innerException it says `"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CommentID', table " ...` and its pointing to my context where i have a relationship defined..please check my relationship and help me finding this where i have delclared that null is not allowed in Comment ID...

1. 1 user can have many posts, can create many tags, can have many
   comments
2. 1 post can have 1 user, many comments, and can have many tags
3. 1 tag can have 1 user, many post
4. 1 comment can have 1 user, 1 post

## RelationShip...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(p => p.Posts).WithRequired(u => u.Users).HasForeignKey(P=>P.UserID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(t => t.Tags).WithRequired(u => u.Users);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(c => c.Comments).WithRequired(u => u.Users);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasRequired(u => u.Users).WithMany(p=>p.Posts);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(t => t.Tags).WithMany(p => p.Posts);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasOptional(c => c.Comments);


            modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasRequired(u => u.Users);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasRequired(p => p.Posts);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasRequired(u => u.Users);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasMany(p => p.Posts).WithMany(t => t.Tags);
```

## Model - User

```
[ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="First Name is Required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is Required")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress,ErrorMessage="please enter valid email")]
        [DisplayName("Email Address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is Required")]
        [Remote("CheckUniqueEmail","User",ErrorMessage="An account with this email address already exists.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is Required")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public DateTime? LastActivityDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

## Model - Post

```
[Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public int PostID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Body { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int? CommentID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int? TagID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

        public virtual User Users { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

## Model = Comment

```
[Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public int CommentID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Your Comment")]
        public string Body { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public int PostID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }

        public Post Posts { get; set; }
```

## model = Tag

```
[Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public int TagID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public User Users { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

Comment: can you post your models here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post your Models here to go in to more details.But as I can see there are several issues with your model configuration.
As you said,

```
1 comment can have 1 user, 1 post
```

so what's the point of  keeping colllection of users in `Comment`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasRequired(u => u.Users);
```

it shoud be like this

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().HasRequired(u => u.User);
```

and this is also applied for `Post` as well.

Comment: appreciate your time ..please have a look at the updated code in question...thx

Comment: ah ok.First thing is don't use meaningful names. You need to use singular terms for single entity. In post  ` public User Users { get; set; }` shuld be   `public User User { get; set; }` . And what's the posint of keeping 'CommentId' in post?

Comment: thats right... no point of putting commentID in post ..i thought how i am gonna track the comments for a perticular post....i can track in comments using the post id ....am i right ? ..

Comment: yes you are right. Because it is a one to many relationship you need to have the `PostId`  in `Comment` model.